# what's `set ovs_ctl ${1-start}` command in linux shell mean?

Tags: linux, shell, openvswitch

I'm reading ovs' script, in start/stop script, there is :

```
start () {
    set ovs_ctl ${1-start}
    set "$@" --system-id=random 
    ...
```

what's `set ovs_ctl ${1-start}` means?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a bash parameter substitution with a default.

```
${parameter-default}, ${parameter:-default}
If parameter not set, use default.
```

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html

So in your case it will set "ovs_ctl" to $1, the first command line argument if it is set, or else "start"

Answer (score 0):

@spkeadoke explained it well, but maybe a little bit clearer documentation is in the bash manual [3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)